# Laravel | Fetch query results by matching multiple where conditions on multiple columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause, relationship, has-many

I have two tables , **users** and **user_skills** [Schema Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8SkM.png). Each user can have multiple skills where there are experience in number of years associated with each skills .

**users**

| id | name | email | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | a@mail | 15 |
| 2 | C | c@mail | 16 |
| 3 | D | d@mail | 17 |

**user_skills**

| id | user_id | skill_id | experience |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 2 |

I want to fetch the users who have skill 1 with experience between 1 to 5 and skill 2 with experience greater than 3 .

I already tried with has many relationship ,

```
$min=1;
$max=5; 
$skillId=1; 
$min2=3;
$max2='';
$skillId2=2;

$searchQuery=$searchQuery
                ->whereHas('getSkill', function ($query) use ($min, $max, $skillId, $min2, $max2, $skillId2) {
                    $query =  $query->where('skill_id', $skillId);
                    if (!empty($max) && !empty($min)) {
                        $query=$query->whereBetween('experience', [$min, $max]);
                    } }
                    
                    $query =  $query->where('skill_id', $skillId2);
                    if (!empty($min2) && !empty($max2)) {
                        $query=$query->where('experience','>', $min2);
                    } }
                
                );
```

here `getSkill` is my relationship with has many . The query does not give any error but yields no result . If i don't use the second `where clause` i get my results .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using $query variable twice in a same code block. Instead of single ->whereHas you can try following.

```
$searchQuery = $searchQuery
    ->whereHas('getSkill', function ($query) use ($min, $max, $skillId) {
        $query =  $query->where('skill_id', $skillId);
        if (!empty($max) && !empty($min)) {
            $query = $query->whereBetween('experience', [$min, $max]);
        }
    })
    ->whereHas('getSkill', function ($query) use ($min2, $skillId2) {
        $query =  $query->where('skill_id', $skillId2);
        if (!empty($min2)) {
            $query = $query->where('experience','>', $min2);
        }
    });
```